# Onblur triggering everywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events, onblur

**Update**

It appears that the input is locked until I input a well formatted email address and then and only then is the element able to be unlock/unfocus. That is just weird, because if I can't focus any other element then how can the `unfocus` event get trigger when the current element is still focus. Do you suppose it has to do with something on the server side then?

---

So I have this piece of code that has an input html generated by the server so I can not directly do the `onblur=function()` in the tag. Instead I use the `onclick` event of the `td` to bind an event handler to the  input.

```
<td id="emailInput" class="label" onclick="emailValidation(event);">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.EmailAddress, new { Class = "ignore"})                        
</td>
<td id="emailValidate" style="display: none">
   <label>Please enter a valid email address</label> 
</td>
```

in the Javascript file I bind the event handler like so:

```
function emailValidation(e) {
  $(e.target).on("blur", function () {        
    console.log("what target e is");
    console.log(e.target);
    var inputVal = $(e.target).val();        
    var re = /[A-z0-9]*[\.?[\w+]+[A-z0-9]+@[A-z0-9][\.?[\w+]+\.[A-z][A-z][A-z]/;
    if (!re.test(inputVal)) {
        $(e.target).focus();
        $("#emailValidate").css("display", "inline-block");
    } else {
        $("#emailValidate").css("display", "none");
    }
  }); 
}
```

I check the dev console and e.target is the input element I want. What is happening is that the `onblur` event in being trigger after it has been appended and the input is `unfocus` even though the input element is no longer focus, and I am just clicking random area in the screen. Am I mis-understanding something? Is there a better definition that I can get than [the w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp), [the developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onblur), and [this weird one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

I was trying to create a JSfiddle (w/o server stuff) to demonstrate and it worked fine so upon closer inspection I see the the input element is not being `unfocus`. It does not matter where I click the cursor remains in the text area, and no other element can be focus now.

**Edit 2**

As requested the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mn5E4/), but it works here but not on the one with server side stuff

Comment: Is your input generated after you click the `<td>`? Is your input inside `<td>`? Show us the Fiddle. `event.target` is the target that generated the event.

Comment: @PHPglue that what I thought too, but looking at the console.log it is the input element not the td element that is the target

Comment: Since your input is inside the `<td>` tag. It can be a target as well.

Comment: If your input is being created by an AJAX process, then it would be undefined, because you need to run this code inside your AJAX function that executes upon completion. Of course, there would be no need to write your code like this at all if that was the case.

Comment: It not being generated by an ajax process I think. I know that I am not doing any ajax call, maybe it is being done in the background?

Comment: How do you not know what is creating your code? We can't help if you don't know.

Comment: Well I am using this plugin the creates it for me, and I have to define some properties in my model with some data attribute. So when I call the model's property `@Html.EditorFor` does it's magic and work with the plugin to generate the HTML. I am not completely sure how that plugin works either, or if I can tell you how or post code from it since it not mine to post to the public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mn5E4/1/

```
$("#emailMe").on("blur", function () {   
    var inputVal = $(this).val();       
    var re = /[A-z0-9]*[\.?[\w+]+[A-z0-9]+@[A-z0-9][\.?[\w+]+\.[A-z][A-z][A-z]/;
    if (!re.test(inputVal)) {
        $("#emailMe").focus();
        $("#emailValidate").css("display", "inline-block");
    } else {
        $("#emailValidate").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

You don't need to bother with using the click event to attach the handler since you know the id of the input you want to bind to.

Edit: Note that this is a fork of your jsFiddle. Based on the code in your question, I would expect the id of the desired input element to be "EmailAddress", in which case you would replace $("#emailMe") with $("#EmailAddress").

Edit2: You can take out any guesswork by doing this:

```
<td id="emailInput" class="label">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.EmailAddress, new { @class = "ignore validateEmail"})                        
</td>
<td id="emailValidate" style="display: none">
   <label>Please enter a valid email address</label> 
</td>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(".validateEmail").on("blur", function () {   
    var inputVal = $(this).val();       
    var re = /[A-z0-9]*[\.?[\w+]+[A-z0-9]+@[A-z0-9][\.?[\w+]+\.[A-z][A-z][A-z]/;
    if (!re.test(inputVal)) {
        $(".validateEmail").focus();
        $("#emailValidate").css("display", "inline-block");
    } else {
        $("#emailValidate").css("display", "none");
    }
});
</script>
```

Note that I passed another class into the EditorFor helper and changed how the class attribute was named to use @ to escape the lower case name "class".

Comment: The problem is that I have no reference to the input element since it is generated by the server at runtime I believe.

Comment: That is true, but it has a predictable id. ASP.NET MVC will use the name of the model property as the ID of the element. See my edit for the expected id.

Comment: I check the dev console and a id is already assign to the element when it is generated. I already tried giving it an Id manually no work, I can on the other hand can find out what the id of the element is after it has been created adn use that in my jquery but feel that is a bit hackish and if they where to update the plugin and the naming convention change it will break my code. But idk if that is the only way then I probably will have to do it.

Comment: I've updated with a way that doesn't rely on the id. Really you can use jQuery to select any property. I will however note that you seem to be under the impression that Html.EditorFor is part of some plugin. It is not. It is part of the core ASP.NET MVC feature set and is very unlikely to change.

Comment: To avoid another update I'll add this other jquery selector you could use: `$("#emailInput input")`. That will select an input that is the child of the td with id=emailInput. In that case you are completely independent from the generated markup except relying that it will create an input which is a core assumption.

Comment: it not html.editor that I am saying is a plugin, I am saying that the plugin that I use is the plugin. The plugin does something IDK what but it require me to declare a property in my model with certains data member and attribute for it to work.

Comment: Thnx I will take that

Answer (score -1):

Please try this aproach:

```
<td id="emailInput" class="label" onclick="emailValidation(event);">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.EmailAddress, new { Class = "ignore"})                        
</td>

 $("#emailInput").on('focusin', "input", function (e) {

    var inputobj = $(this);

        var inputVal = inputobj.val(); 

    var re = /[A-z0-9]*[\.?[\w+]+[A-z0-9]+@[A-z0-9][\.?[\w+]+\.[A-z][A-z][A-z]/;
    if (!re.test(inputVal)) {
        inputobj.focus();
        $("#emailValidate").css("display", "inline-block");
    } else {
        $("#emailValidate").css("display", "none");
    }


})
```

**Note**: Not tested

Comment: I get an `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score -2):

You should use $(this)

```
var inputVal = $(this).val();
```

Comment: Did not work and I notice something please see my Edit above.